# Is it possible to make WordPress page attribute meta box select option display as images?

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I am customizing the page attribute meta box for posts pages on a WordPress them I am developing. I will have multiple templates to choose from for each post and I was wondering if there is a way I can replace the select > option text where the templates show to display as images of how each template would look and the user would then select one of them and the correspondent template would be selected. Have tried a million things but nothing seems to do it... Would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Replace? I think you could try removing the metabox and replacing it with your own, but I don' know how that would affect the overall functionality of the theme. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box

Comment: Well, no need to remove any metabox, we have to implement this with that template metabox.

Comment: I am being able to make it work as a normal dropdown with text but what I am trying to achieve is something like this http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/ where the dropdown post templates would show as thumnails. Have tried that plugin but cant seem to make it work..

Comment: Well your idea is good and what I think..yes it is possible...Now I am trying to make a plugin which fulfills your functionality...But have you searched this in google? maybe some such wordpress plugin exists...

Comment: I am trying to do it without a plugin. I am wondering if there is a way of using images which then would be selectable instead of the select tag that WordPress uses by default for choosing the template for the post, since making the html option tags in the select tag display as images seems to be a nightmare..

Comment: Well, without plugin, how's it being possible...May be some hook exists for this ....but this also requires some coding...we have to write a code to do this and if plugin used, its got easier...And what about images which appears in dropdown..definitely those images also come from the user which he uploaded...

Comment: No, I don't think I am expressing myself well. What I am trying to do is to use the "Page Attributes" that allows a user to choose a template for the page in the POSTS editor. So basically the "Page Attributes" page template selector for posts. Then I would create multiple templates(full, width, sidebar left, etc) and the user would then be able to choose a page template from all the post page templates available to display the post. I have come this far.

Comment: I have been able to implement this functionality, however at the moment a specific template can be chosen from a drop down menu where the available templates names display and this is what I am struggling with, because ideally I would want to create small images illustrating the template look and users could then select the thumbnail corresponding to the template look they wish the post to be shown as.

Comment: So basically I am trying to create a way of showing the post templates available as small selectable images instead of showing them as a drop down list which is the default WordPress functionality for this. Any possible solutions would be really appreciated. Meanwhile Ill keep trying to find a way. Thank you very much.

Comment: have you find any solution ?

Comment: Yes, basically I have replaced the select option tags by input radio tags and added images to it. Thanks anyway