# How to convert the WordPress meta box Page Attributes->Page Template dropdown to radio buttons?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I would like to be able to change the Page Attribute "Templates" dropdown to radio buttons, to allow me to have corresponding thumbnails next to them.

It looks like this question was already asked here  - [Is it possible to make WordPress page attribute meta box select option display as images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515085/is-it-possible-to-make-wordpress-page-attribute-meta-box-select-option-display-a) - however no code was ever supplied and looking at the comments it appears that the user answered their own question?

I have already removed and replaced the Page Attributes meta box on functions.php, as per below:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse44966_add_meta_box' );
function wpse44966_add_meta_box( $post_type ){ 
    remove_meta_box(
        'pageparentdiv',
        'page',
        'side');
    add_meta_box(
        'wpse44966-meta-box',
        'page' == $post_type ? __('Page Style Templates') : __('Attributes'),
        'wpse44966_meta_box_cb', 
        'page', 
        'side', 
        'low');
}
```

I am then able to call back the "Templates" dropdown in my own meta box - I have also included the *page_template_dropdown* function (renamed '*page_template_dropdown_show_it*').

```
function page_template_dropdown_show_it( $default = '', $post_type = 'page' ) {
    $templates = get_page_templates( null, $post_type );
    ksort( $templates );
    foreach ( array_keys( $templates ) as $template ) {
        $selected = selected( $default, $templates[ $template ], false );
        echo "\n\t<option value='" . esc_attr( $templates[ $template ] ) . "' $selected>" . esc_html( $template ) . '</option>';
    }
}

function wpse44966_meta_box_cb( $post ){
    echo 'Please select from the below'; 
    if ( count( get_page_templates( $post ) ) > 0 && get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) != $post->ID ) :
        $template = ! empty( $post->page_template ) ? $post->page_template : false;  ?>
        <p class="post-attributes-label-wrapper"><label class="post-attributes-label" for="page_template"><?php _e( 'Template' ); ?></label><?php do_action( 'page_attributes_meta_box_template', $template, $post ); ?></p>
        <select name="page_template" id="page_template">
            <?php $default_title = apply_filters( 'default_page_template_title', __( 'Default Template' ), 'meta-box' ); ?>
            <option value="default"><?php echo esc_html( $default_title ); ?></option>
            <?php page_template_dropdown_show_it( $template, $post->post_type ); ?>
        </select>
    <?php endif;
}
```

However, when I then amend both *page_template_dropdown_show_it* and *wpse44966_meta_box_cb* to show radio buttons, the changes are applied visually but nothing happens when you select them?

```
function page_template_dropdown_show_it( $default = '', $post_type = 'page' ) {
    $templates = get_page_templates( null, $post_type );
    ksort( $templates );
    foreach ( array_keys( $templates ) as $template ) {
        $checked = checked( $default, $templates[ $template ], false );
        echo "\n\t<input type='radio' name='page_template' value='" . esc_attr( $templates[ $template ] ) . "' $checked>" . esc_html( $template );
    }
}

function wpse44966_meta_box_cb( $post ){
    echo 'Please select from the below'; 
    if ( count( get_page_templates( $post ) ) > 0 && get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) != $post->ID ) :
        $template = ! empty( $post->page_template ) ? $post->page_template : false;  ?>
        <p class="post-attributes-label-wrapper"><label class="post-attributes-label" for="page_template"><?php _e( 'Template' ); ?></label><?php do_action( 'page_attributes_meta_box_template', $template, $post ); ?></p>
            <?php $default_title = apply_filters( 'default_page_template_title', __( 'Default Template' ), 'meta-box' ); ?>
            <input type='radio' name='page_template' value="default"><?php echo esc_html( $default_title ); ?>
            <?php page_template_dropdown_show_it( $template, $post->post_type ); ?>
    <?php endif;
}
```

It's obviously not as simple as a straight swap-out (as it isn't working), but the only thing that I can see that is missing is now there is nothing carrying the id="page_template", whereas before it was included in the below:

```
<select name="page_template" id="page_template">
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears that I was correct that the issue was that the id "page_template" was no longer being passed.

To solve this, all I have done is applied some Javascript (using the [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) function) which adds the id "page_template" to the radio button that has been selected.